# How to make fwrite() write in the middle of the text file

Tags: php

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$steps = $_GET['id'];
$myfile = fopen("save/" . $username . ".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $steps);
fclose($myfile);
echo $steps;
```

This is my code, The issue is that it is replacing the whole .txt file with just $steps while `Test1|b7f2b0b64a3c60a367b40b579b06452d|Male|0|a|02/05/2016|1` is in the text file which therefore it ends up being just `32` `if $steps = 32;` in the text file, I want to replace the `0` with `$steps = $_GET['id'];`

hint I know its something like this

```
explode('|',$....)
```

Comment: You're looking for `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv` preferrably. Long-term you probably want to use a database instead (and a proper password hashing function - from the looks of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are replacing the file's contents entirely, with `$steps`, which only contains the `$_GET['id']`.

Your explode idea can work towards this end, if you are sure that the steps will always be in the same place. Then it'd go somewhat like this.

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$steps = $_GET['id'];
$myfile = fopen("save/" . $username . ".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
//explode on the |
$userData = explode('|', stream_get_contents($myfile)); 
//This should be the steps data. Replace it with the new value
$userData[3] = $steps;
//put the exploded string back together with the new steps value
fwrite($myfile, implode("|", $userData));
fclose($myfile);
```

`fopen` and `fclose` are quite intense operations for such small files, though. A possibly faster way (and easier, too!) is to do it like this:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$steps = $_GET['id'];
$myfile = file_get_contents("save/$username.txt");
//explode on the |
$userData = explode('|', $myfile); 
//This should be the steps data. Replace it with the new value
$userData[3] = $steps;
//put the exploded string back together with the new steps value
file_put_contents("save/$username.txt", implode("|", $userData));
```

p.s. you can use `$variables` within the double `"` strings.

Comment: |32

was the save text result

Comment: Are you sure you changed the `fwrite`'s value from `$steps` to `$userData`? -- if you are, are you sure you're using a file with a full string right now, and not one you've just overwritten to single step value?

Comment: I just copy and pasted your version of the code. and the txt file came as |32           and there is no other php code on that page except ^that^

Comment: Yes, ok. But was the file still intact as `Test1|b7f2b0b64a3c60a367b40b579b06452d|Male|0|a|02/05/2016|1`? Did you make sure to restore it? If you're testing on a file that only had `32` in it, that would be a reason for it to go wrong.

Comment: I started with `Test1|b7f2b0b64a3c60a367b40b579b06452d|Male|0|a|02/05/2016|1`
but once i run that php code it just made it `|32`

Comment: Ok. I just made a testscript and it works 100% perfectly for me.
Could you `echo stream_get_contents($myfile);` for me and show me the result? (before the `fwrite`)

Comment: No output was created,
so blank page

Comment: Then that's where we have the issue. `stream_get_contents()` is clearly not working.  I'll write out a 2nd script which should work, then. A script that is probably faster, anyway.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a way that should work regardless of how the stream is handled. I hope that this will prove to be more effective.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are using the `w` file mode, which will truncate the file on opening it. This means you **will be losing data** if you don't set it aside first. As per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) you could first read the data and then save the entire string back to the file:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$steps = $_GET['id'];
$myfile = fopen("save/" . $username . ".txt", "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");

// Get the current data from the file
$data = fgetcsv($myfile, 0, '|');

// Now replace the 4th column with our steps
$data[3] = $steps;

// Now truncate the file
ftruncate($myfile, 0);

// And save the new data back to the file
fwrite($myfile, implode('|', $data));
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Why overcomplicate things with complicated `regex` when a simple `explode()` would do just fine?

Comment: @Bamuel I adjusted the answer to use `fgetcsv` instead. Also noted a problem with the file read mode and added an explanation for that.

Comment: Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in ****.php on line 16

Comment: @Bamuel My bad, missed an implode there. Added now.